# Yocto recipe for systemd USER service

Tags: systemd, yocto

I'm trying to create a yocto recipe in order to add an to enable a systemd user service.

The problem is that, since the service is installed in systemd/user, with bitbake I get this error:

> ERROR: mediumlevel-service-1.0-r0 do_package:
>   SYSTEMD_SERVICE_mediumlevel-service value mediumlevel.service does not
>   exist

My recipe is:

```
SUMMARY = "Launch mediumlevel at boot"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

inherit systemd

SRC_URI = "file://mediumlevel.service \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "mediumlevel.service"

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${systemd_user_unitdir}
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/mediumlevel.service ${D}${systemd_user_unitdir}
}

FILES_${PN} += "/usr/lib/systemd/user"

REQUESTED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "systemd"
```

What do you think?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

systemd.bbclass takes only care for system services not user services.

I guess you have to do something like this:

Remove the SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} variable

```
FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_user_unitdir}"

pkg_postinst_${PN} () {
    #!/bin/sh -e
    OPTS=""
    if [ -n "$D" ]; then
        OPTS="--root=$D"
    fi
    systemctl ${OPTS} --user enable mediumlevel.service
}
```

Maybe you need to remove even the `inherit systemd` line, because the class sets pkg_postinst.

Comment: It does not work this way. Yocto uses stub for `systemctl` without `--user` support. See my answer for working solution.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if the answer is still relevant for you, but I wanted to drop it here anyways.

I believe your problem comes from the install step and the files for the package. I can see you tried to install the service on the folder, but that doesn't seem to work well with Yocto. You need to provide the filename together with the folder. Same on the FILE_${PN}. This recipe should work better:

```
SUMMARY = "Launch mediumlevel at boot"
LICENSE = "MIT"
LIC_FILES_CHKSUM = "file://${COMMON_LICENSE_DIR}/MIT;md5=0835ade698e0bcf8506ecda2f7b4f302"

inherit systemd

SRC_URI = "file://mediumlevel.service \
"

S = "${WORKDIR}"

SYSTEMD_SERVICE_${PN} = "mediumlevel.service"

do_install() {
        install -d ${D}${systemd_user_unitdir}
        install -m 0644 ${WORKDIR}/mediumlevel.service ${D}${systemd_user_unitdir}/mediumlevel.service
}

FILES_${PN} += "${systemd_user_unitdir}/mediumlevel.service"

REQUESTED_DISTRO_FEATURES = "systems"
```

I hope it can help you or someone else :)

Answer (score 0):

The systemd user service could be enabled in Yocto in the following way:

```
inherit systemd

SRC_URI = "file://mediumlevel.service"

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${systemd_user_unitdir}
    install -m 0644 ${S}/mediumlevel.service ${D}${systemd_user_unitdir}
}

pkg_postinst:${PN}() {
    mkdir -p $D${sysconfdir}/systemd/user/default.target.wants
    ln -s ${systemd_user_unitdir}/mediumlevel.service $D${sysconfdir}/systemd/user/default.target.wants/mediumlevel.service
}
```

This method is equivalent to running on the target device:

```
systemctl --global enable mediumlevel.service
```

Comment: Welcome to the site, and thank you for your contribution. Please consider editing your post to indicate which file needs to be modified with the presented content in order to enable the service.